# scatter plot d3.js freecodecamp pronect having trouble with yscale displaying minutes

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I had completed all 14 user stories, except 2, userstory #6 and #12 they are related to each other (about YScale domain and range, and converting it to minutes)
It's been two days I stuck on this, I will share my code
Can anyone tell me  what is the bug in my code.

```
##https://codepen.io/codebrakerk/pen/ZEWOPpz
```

---

[image: Ref Image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to access "Time" from your dataset.

```
{
"Time": "36:50",
"Place": 1,
"Seconds": 2210,
"Name": "Marco Pantani",
"Year": 1995,
"Nationality": "ITA",
"Doping": "Alleged drug use during 1995 due to high hematocrit levels",
"URL": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marco_Pantani#Alleged_drug_use"
}
```

I guess the "Seconds" attribute implies the time it took for the person to complete his run. Your time code should run as follows:

```
(item) => {
    let t = item["Time"].split(':');
    return new Date(minutes=t[0], seconds=t[1]);
}
```